# Java.net. Сокеты

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста по сокетам. Имеется код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceServer {

    String[] adviceList = {"Ешьте меньшими порциями", "Купите облегающие джинсы. Нет, они сделают вас "
            + "полнее.", "Два слова: не годится", "Будьте честны хотя бы сегодня. Скажите своему "
            + "начальнику все, что вы *на самом деле* о нем думаете.", "Возможно, вам "
            + "стоит подобрать другую прическу."};

    public void go() {

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(4242);

            while(true) {
                Socket sock = serverSock.accept();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                String advice = getAdvice();
                writer.println(advice);
                writer.close();
                System.out.println(advice);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getAdvice() {
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * adviceList.length);
        return adviceList[random];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DailyAdviceServer server = new DailyAdviceServer();
        server.go();

    }

}
```

Интересует этот фрагмент:

```
 try {
    ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(4242);

    while(true) {
        Socket sock = serverSock.accept();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        String advice = getAdvice();
        writer.println(advice);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(advice);
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Здесь создается серверный сокет, присваивается порт.
Но не могу никак понять как работает метод `accept()`. Как я понял он ждет соединения от клиента. Т.е. если клиент не инициировал подключение, то эти строчки не выполняются?

```
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        String advice = getAdvice();
        writer.println(advice);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(advice);
```

Answer (score 2):

В [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) к методу `java.net.ServerSocket.accept()`, указано

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts
>      It. The method blocks until a connection is made.

Это значит, что операция блокирующая. Пока на сокет на придет соединение, поток на сервере будет ждать в этом методе подключения.